# Parsing several xml files at once in Python

Tags: python, xml

Hi there all you fine people of SO!

Ok, so I'm trying to parse xml files using the lxml module (package?) in Python. Here is my method:

```
def read_xml(filename):
    """Reads xml and strips tags
    creates a string with file"""
    tree = etree.parse(filename)
    no_tags = etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf-8', method='text')
    no_tags = re.sub(ur'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', no_tags, re.UNICODE)
```

This function works, but for some xml files I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arashsaidi/Work/TextLab/Code/academic_dictionary/file_io/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    read_xml("../Corpus/artikler-xml/fn.xml")
  File "/Users/arashsaidi/Work/TextLab/Code/academic_dictionary/file_io/read_single_file.py", line 14, in read_xml
    tree = etree.parse(filename)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3239, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:69970)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1749, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102081)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1775, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102345)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1679, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101380)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1110, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96832)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91290)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92476)
  File "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91772)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document, line 2, column 6
```

This file consists of several xml files in one file. Any suggestions how I would go about parsing such a file?

Comment: That's a nonstandard XML file. `lxml` is telling you as much.

Comment: @nneonneo Yeah, I know it's nonstandard as it is one file containing many xml units, my question was how I would go about solving this. I can't put each of the xml units in its own file, as the file is huge, and that would take me forever, which unfortunately, I don't have (I wouldn't study programming if I had unlimited time, then I would just do everything by hand, maybe live in the woods, become rugged and cool)